# How to parse XSD and read all the complex elements and its child elements using the Java and XmlSchema Core

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xmlschema

I am using the `Apache XmlSchema Core` library to parse the `XSD` file and get all the elements and its children type (datatype, maxOccurs, etc). I am following the documentation [Apache XML SCHEMA CORE](http://ws.apache.org/xmlschema/xmlschema-core/apidocs/index.html) and trying to do. But after navigating to a certain point I am getting a bit confused. Can someone please guide me on how can I traverse through my `XSD` file and get all the elements and its child elements along with the related information?

I am able to get all the XSD information in my `schema` element I just want to know how can I access the child elements from my root `RootFood` and get its related information. Any help would be really appreciated.

I tried to continue further and this is what I have so far:
The element `RootFood` belongs to the instance of the class `XmlSchemaGroupParticle`. I tried to debug the code to find the elements that are associated with my `rootParticles`, it has the field called `items` within which I have my `food` element `items->[0]->namedDelegate->qName->localPart` but when I try to add `GET` method on `rootParticles` to obtain the `items` then there is no such method.

The `XmlSchemaParticle` extends following classes: `XmlSchemaAnnotated`, `XmlSchemaObject`, and implements the interface `XmlSchemaObjectBase` but none of them have the field called `Items`.

Following is the Java code I have so far, I tried several things:

```
public class XMLSchemaCore {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException,
        FileNotFoundException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException {
            String xsdPath = Paths.get(XMLSchemaCore.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.xsd").toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath();
            String filePath = Path.of(xsdPath).toString();

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            XmlSchemaCollection schemaCol = new XmlSchemaCollection();

            // Schema contain the complete XSD content which needs to be parsed
            XmlSchema schema = schemaCol.read(new StreamSource(is));
            // schema.write(System.out);
            for (Map.Entry<QName, XmlSchemaElement> entry: schema.getElements().entrySet()) {
                // Root element and its contents
                QName parentElementName = entry.getKey();
                XmlSchemaElement parentElementValues = entry.getValue();

                // Get the elements based on the Root element
                XmlSchemaElement root = schema.getElementByName(parentElementName);

                // Get the type of the root element
                XmlSchemaType type = root != null ? root.getSchemaType() : null;

                // Check if the root element is of Complex type
                if (type instanceof XmlSchemaComplexType) {
                    // Get the Particles associated with the element
                    XmlSchemaParticle rootParticles = ((XmlSchemaComplexType) type).getParticle();

                    // Check particle belongs to which type
                    if (rootParticles instanceof XmlSchemaAny) {
                        System.out.println("Any Schema Type");

                    } else if (rootParticles instanceof XmlSchemaElement) {
                        System.out.println("Element Schema Type");

                    } else if (rootParticles instanceof XmlSchemaGroupParticle) {
                        System.out.println("Group Schema Type");
                        System.out.println(rootParticles);
                        System.out.println(rootParticles);

                    } else if (rootParticles instanceof XmlSchemaGroupRef) {
                        System.out.println("Group Ref Schema Type");

                    }
                }
            }

        }

}
```

Following is the `XSD` file I have:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="RootFood">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="food">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name" />
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="price" />
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description" />
                            <xs:element type="xs:short" name="calories" />
                            <xs:element name="ingredients">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ingredient"
                                            maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

[image]

Comment: Finally, after a lot of try, I was able to do it. Please find the code below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying a lot of things I was able to get the code working. Posting the code here as it may help somebody who is planning to use [Apache XMLSchema Core Library for XML/XSD parsing](https://ws.apache.org/xmlschema/). I know how much frustrating it is as we do not have some good examples on the internet for this parsing library. Hope this helps.

Basically, this code will parse the whole `XSD` file and store the elements in the `HashMap` based on its parent and child element. You can obtain the Parent for any XSD element also you can get the information related to the child such as its parent etc. Check the [XmlSchemaElement](https://ws.apache.org/xmlschema/xmlschema-core/apidocs/index.html) to get further details on the information for each child:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema;
import org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaAny;
import org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection;
import org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaComplexType;
import org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaElement;
import org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaGroupRef;
import org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaParticle;
import org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSequence;
import org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSequenceMember;
import org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaType;

public class XMLSchemaCore {

    private static XmlSchemaCollection xmlSchemaCollection;
    private static Map<QName, List<XmlSchemaElement>> xsdElements = new HashMap<QName, List<XmlSchemaElement>>();
    private static List<XmlSchemaElement> schemaElements = new ArrayList<XmlSchemaElement>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // Path for the file which is stored within the Resource folder
        String xsdPath = Paths.get(XMLSchemaCore.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.xsd").toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath();
        String filePath = Path.of(xsdPath).toString();

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        xmlSchemaCollection = new XmlSchemaCollection();

        // Schema contain the complete XSD content which needs to be parsed
        XmlSchema schema = xmlSchemaCollection.read(new StreamSource(is));
        // schema.write(System.out);

        // Get the root element from XSD
        Map.Entry<QName, XmlSchemaElement> entry = schema.getElements().entrySet().iterator().next();
        QName rootElement = entry.getKey();

        // Get all the elements based on the parent element
        XmlSchemaElement childElement = xmlSchemaCollection.getElementByQName(rootElement);

        // Call method to get all the child elements
        getChildElementNames(childElement);

        String element = "" + xsdElements.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + " -- " + String.join(", ", e.getValue().stream().map(v -> v
                            .getQName().toString()).collect(Collectors.toList()))).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(element);
    }

    // Method to check for the child elements and return list
    private static void getChildElementNames(XmlSchemaElement element) {

        // Get the type of the element
        XmlSchemaType elementType = element != null ? element.getSchemaType() : null;

        // Confirm if the element is of Complex type
        if (elementType instanceof XmlSchemaComplexType) {
            // Get all particles associated with that element Type
            XmlSchemaParticle allParticles = ((XmlSchemaComplexType) elementType).getParticle();

            // Check particle belongs to which type
            if (allParticles instanceof XmlSchemaAny) {
                System.out.println("Any Schema Type");

            } else if (allParticles instanceof XmlSchemaElement) {
                System.out.println("Element Schema Type");

            } else if (allParticles instanceof XmlSchemaSequence) {
                // System.out.println("Sequence Schema Type");
                final XmlSchemaSequence xmlSchemaSequence = (XmlSchemaSequence) allParticles;
                final List<XmlSchemaSequenceMember> items = xmlSchemaSequence.getItems();
                items.forEach((item) -> {
                    XmlSchemaElement itemElements = (XmlSchemaElement) item;
                    schemaElements.add(itemElements);
                    // System.out.println(" Parent : " + element.getQName() + " -- Child : " +
                    // itemElements.getQName());
                    //Call the method to add the current element as child
                    addChild(element.getQName(), itemElements);
                    // Call method recursively to get all subsequent element
                    getChildElementNames(itemElements);
                    schemaElements = new ArrayList<XmlSchemaElement>();
                });

            } else if (allParticles instanceof XmlSchemaGroupRef) {

            }
        }
    }

    // Add child elements based on its parent
    public static void addChild(QName qName, XmlSchemaElement child) {
        List<XmlSchemaElement> values = xsdElements.get(qName);
        if (values == null) {
            values = new ArrayList<XmlSchemaElement>();
        }
        values.add(child);
        xsdElements.put(qName, values);
    }

}
```